# format time input on form for 3 dropdown boxes

Tags: php, cakephp

In Cakephp I have got a form input of type time. The user selects the time from 3 drop down boxes (hrs,mins and am/pm). I need the user to be able to select no time option called 'not available'

I have an option to select  'not available' so the user has the option of not specifying a time. This works as  shown below.

I have a drop down box of time and needed to select a not available option on the hour. Instead of selecting the not available on the minute dropdown box and am.pm I wanted the minute and am/pm drop boxes to automatically set to not available when I select this option on the hour.

```
       echo $this->Form->input('mon_start', 
                                            array('label'=> 'Start','type' => 'time', 'style'=>'width: 80px', 'empty' => 'not available', 'selected'=>$monstart));
```

Comment: it would be more helpful if I get some feedback so I can add extra content or find the solution if one exists.

Comment: I have a drop down box of time and needed to select a not available option on the hour. Instead of selecting the not available on the minute dropdown box and am.pm I wanted the minute and am/pm drop boxes to automatically set to not available when I select this option on the hour.

Comment: I have made this question clearer so please let me post

Comment: can this post be amended please as I cant post anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little unspecific, so here's an unspecific answer.

You have to use JavaScript, check the selected value in the `onchange` event, and set the selected options for the other select elements based on the selected value.

Here's a jQuery based example.

**JS**

```
var selects = $('.selectlr').on('change', function()
{
    if($(this).find(':selected').val() === 'none')
    {
        selects.find('[value="none"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectlr">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="selectlr">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select class="selectlr">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**Fiddle**

**http://jsfiddle.net/7g97no5a/**